# BufferedReader reads nothing and then terminates the program, why is this?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm writing a program for an assignment wherein I am supplied population data and child poverty rates by each high school in the country and what I am supposed to do is only read certain columns of data and write them into another new text file, and then another program prints out this information. I try to do this by creating a while loop that reads each line of the file (13486 lines), assigns certain indices of each line to their corresponding arrays and array indices as strings, and then moves onto the next while loop wherein these data are printed in new columns. From there, I want to average the values for each state and print them in the second program. However, I'm not even there yet.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String[] states =
    { "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA",
            "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD",
            "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ",
            "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC",
            "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" };
    File censusData = new File(args[0]);
    if (!censusData.exists())
    {
        System.err.print("Census Data not found.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This file definitely exists.");
    }
    // Scanner cdr = new Scanner(censusData);
    // cdr.useDelimiter("\n");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(censusData);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] stateCode = new int[13486];
    int[] population = new int[13486];
    int[] childPopulation = new int[13486];
    String line = new String();
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        stateCode[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 1));
        population[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(82, 89));
        childPopulation[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(91, 98));
        i++;

    }
    br.close();
    File cD = new File(args[1], "newCensusData.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(cD);
    i = 0;
    while (childPopulation.length < Integer.parseInt(args[2]))
    {
        pw.printf("%4s", stateCode[i], population[i], childPopulation[i]);
        i++;

    }
    pw.close();

}
}
```

`args[0]` is the full path for the file of census information, `args[1]` is the output directory, and `args[2]` is the number of entries in the input text file.

What is happening instead is, according to the debugger, the first while loop runs twice and then the program terminates and I don't know why. The file location, output location, everything else is good. `newCensusData.txt` is even generated but there is no information in there. Can anyone tell me why the `BufferedReader` object isn't actually reading the lines of the text file?

Edit: I don't think that this has much to do where where I chose to close the different reader/writer objects. Even if I do not close either of them, the result is the same.

Comment: You are closing your streams inside the loop. While you are reading `br.close()` and while you are writing `pw.close()`

Comment: That's not it. I put those in the loop as some sort of last-ditch effort (obviously misguided) because before I didn't even close it. Putting the close outside of the loop doesn't help either. I think there's something wrong with my installation of java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the `BufferedReader` (And `PrintWriter`) inside the loop, and according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> Once the stream has been closed, further read(), ready(), mark(), reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException.

Change your loop to:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{

    stateCode[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 1));
    population[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(82, 89));
    childPopulation[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(91, 98));
    i++;        
}
br.close();
```

Comment: I put the close method in the loop to try to fix it as this was happening before I even had a close anywhere

Comment: @CelineDion Then it probably means that it isn't reading your file correctly. Try printing out the contents of the file

Comment: I can't print the contents of that file. What I get instead is an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @CelineDion How are you trying to print the file? Printing the contents should not result in an IndexOutOfBoundsError

Comment: System.out.println(lines.get(0)); -- However when I remove .get(0), I get no error but also no output whatsoever.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(line)` inside of your `while` loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177524/discussion-between-celinedion-and-gblodgett).

Answer (score 1):

You can open up your BufferedReader with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). That way you don't have to worry about explicitly closing your Reader as the statement will take care of it.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        stateCode[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 1));
        population[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(82, 89));
        childPopulation[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(91, 98));
        i++;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    //Catch your exception
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //Catch your exception
}
```

From the documentation:

> The class BufferedReader, in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface java.lang.AutoCloseable. Because the BufferedReader instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method BufferedReader.readLine throwing an IOException).

Comment: or just use `Files.readAllLines`

Comment: I appreciate the help, but as I told GBlodgett, changing where I put the close method hasn't helped. I put the close method in the loop as an attempt to fix the problem and unfortunately left it in there when I posted to StackOverflow